# Join with keys of both tables

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.7

I try to bring to tables together in a join-like way. Consider the column `id_` as "on clause" key. In the tables below, there are more id_s in table 1 than 2. I would like to have all ids and values of both tables. If there is not a respective `id_`, the value is 0 or null.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value1 INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2 (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value2 INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO t1 (id_, value1) VALUES
(1, 10),
(2, 20),
(3, 30)

INSERT INTO t2 (id_, value2) VALUES
(2, 40),
(3, 60)
(4, 80)
```

I use the platform Metabase, a BI tool.

Comment: `FULL JOIN` can be simulated with a `UNION ALL` of a `JOIN` and a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL (which does not support FULL JOIN) you must use gathering subquery:

```
SELECT id_, t1.value1, t2.value2
FROM ( SELECT id_ FROM t1
       UNION 
       SELECT id_ FROM t2 ) total
LEFT JOIN t1 USING (id_)
LEFT JOIN t2 USING (id_);
```

Comment: In case t1 and t2 are not declared tables, but subqueries, do I need to substitute on respective places?

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto True. But I'd recommend to create one query from the same beginning. Or at least look does `total` subquery result may be obtained by third, more simple, subquery.